# How to find out the client operating system version using Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

need the exact os version of the link

navigator.userAgent produces below
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' not able to find exact solution